# How to append values in gloabal variables in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, nsstring

I am very much new to iOS so i don't have an idea.I am developing an application in which i am fetaching data from the server.So i have some of the url from which i will featch the data.I want to decalre all the url in a seperate file & use them in another file.I have created AppConst.h & AppConst.m.

**AppConst.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AppConstant : NSObject

extern NSString const *BASE_URL;
extern NSString const *LOGIN;
extern NSString const *CREATE_ACCOUNT;
extern NSString const *UPDATE_PROFILE;
extern NSString const *ADD_BUSINESS_CARD;
extern NSString const *ADD_NONBUSINESS_CARD;
extern NSString const *ADD_EVENT_CARD;


@end
```

**AppConst.m**

```
#import "AppConstant.h"

@implementation AppConstant
 NSString const *BASE_URL=@"http://localhost:8080/app/v1";
 NSString const *LOGIN=@"/login";
 NSString const *UPDATE_PROFILE=@"/create_account";
 NSString const *ADD_BUSINESS_CARD=@"/addBusinessCard";
 NSString const *ADD_NONBUSINESS_CARD=@"addNonBusinessCard";
 NSString const *ADD_EVENT_CARD=@"addEventCard";



@end
```

But i am not able to append the string of **BASE_URL** with **LOGIN** url.
I get the error as below

```
sending 'const_NSString *__strong' to parameter of type "NSString discards qualifiers.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your constant string as follows:

```
NSString * const kSomeConstantString = @""; // constant pointer
```

The former is a constant pointer to an NSString object, while the later is a pointer to a constant NSString object.

Using a NSString * const prevents you from reassigning kSomeConstantString to point to a different NSString object.

The method isEqualToString: expects an argument of type NSString *. If you pass a pointer to a constant string (const NSString *), you are passing something different than it expects.

Besides, NSString objects are already immutable, so making them const NSString is meaningless.

Or else you can declare constant like this also

```
#define kSomeConstantString  @""
```

Answer (score 0):

better idea to make constants file is to create header file and add all the static constants like below:

```
// Host Url
#define BASE_URL                       @"http://localhost:8080/app/v1"

// login Url
#define LOGIN                          @"/login"
```

and than add the constants file.h in the parent view controller and than you can use everywhere in the app. and even if you want to append string than you can use the below code the create url from your code:

```
 NSString *loginURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASE_URL, LOGIN];
```

Thanks, May be help you to learn new things.